# Python Kuyruk worker in background

Tags: python, worker, kuyruk

After some research of Python worker I finnaly found an easy one : Kuyruk

https://kuyruk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

I manage to use it as I want but I have a question : How could I launch the worker `kuyruk --app tasks.kuyruk` in backgroung, without output on my terminal ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I havent worked on `kyuruk` but isn't `&` working ?

Comment: I tried, but on my terminal it's still display some logs :/